# Paynamics Integration using PHP

Tags: php

I have a project which requires paynamics payment gateway, I have the merchant id and merchant key already, After submitting the form containing the details and amount it must go to payment url, but the transaction is always failed.
However in the paynamics backend it was succcessfully saved, but the status is signature verification failed.

```
$_mid = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //<-- your merchant id
$_requestid = substr(uniqid(), 0, 13);
$_responseid = rand(9,100);
// $_ipaddress = "192.168.10.1";
$_ipaddress = "192.168.51.1";
$_noturl = "http://localhost/aspr/checkout-2/"; // url where response is posted
$_resurl = "http://localhost/aspr/checkout-2/"; //url of merchant landing page
$_cancelurl = "http://localhost/aspr/cancel/"; //url of merchant landing page
$_fname = "Juan"; // kindly set this to first name of the cutomer
$_mname = "O"; // kindly set this to middle name of the cutomer
$_lname = "Dela Cruz"; // kindly set this to last name of the cutomer
$_addr1 = "1609 Cityland 10 HV Dela Costa St.Salecedo Village"; // kindly set this to address1 of the cutomer
$_addr2 = "longos malolos";// kindly set this to address2 of the cutomer
$_city = "makati"; // kindly set this to city of the cutomer
$_state = "MM"; // kindly set this to state of the cutomer
$_country = "PH"; // kindly set this to country of the cutomer
$_zip = "1200"; // kindly set this to zip/postal of the cutomer
$_sec3d = "try3d"; // 
$_email = "technical@paynamics.net"; // kindly set this to email of the cutomer
$_phone = "3308772"; // kindly set this to phone number of the cutomer
$_mobile = "09178134828"; // kindly set this to mobile number of the cutomer
$_clientip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$_amount = number_format((float)20, 2, '.', ''); // kindly set this to the total amount of the transaction. Set the amount to 2 decimal point before generating signature.
$_currency = "PHP"; //PHP or USD

$forSign = $_mid . 
        $_requestid . 
        $_ipaddress . 
        $_noturl . 
        $_resurl .  
        $_fname . 
        $_lname . 
        $_mname . 
        $_addr1 . 
        $_addr2 . 
        $_city . 
        $_state . 
        $_country . 
        $_zip . 
        $_email . 
        $_phone . 
        $_clientip . 
        $_amount . 
        $_currency . 
        $_sec3d . 
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //<-- your merchant key


$_sign = hash("sha512", $forSign);


$strxml = "";
$strxml .= "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>";

$strxml .= "<Request>";
    $strxml .= "<mid>" . $_mid . "</mid>";
    $strxml .= "<request_id>" . $_requestid . "</request_id>";
    $strxml .= "<ip_address>" . $_ipaddress . "</ip_address>";
    $strxml .= "<notification_url>" . $_noturl . "</notification_url>";
    $strxml .= "<response_url>" . $_resurl . "</response_url>";
    $strxml .= "<cancel_url>" . $_cancelurl . "</cancel_url>";
    $strxml .= "<mtac_url>".$_resurl."</mtac_url>"; // pls set this to the url where your terms and conditions are hosted
    $strxml .= "<descriptor_note></descriptor_note>"; // pls set this to the descriptor of the merchant ""
    $strxml .= "<fname>" . $_fname . "</fname>";
    $strxml .= "<lname>" . $_lname . "</lname>";
    $strxml .= "<mname>" . $_mname . "</mname>";
    $strxml .= "<address1>" . $_addr1 . "</address1>";
    $strxml .= "<address2>" . $_addr2 . "</address2>";
    $strxml .= "<city>" . $_city . "</city>";
    $strxml .= "<state>" . $_state . "</state>";
    $strxml .= "<country>" . $_country . "</country>";
    $strxml .= "<zip>" . $_zip . "</zip>";
    $strxml .= "<email>" . $_email . "</email>";
    $strxml .= "<phone>" . $_phone . "</phone>";
    $strxml .= "<mobile>" . $_mobile . "</mobile>";
    $strxml .= "<amount>" . $_amount . "</amount>";
    $strxml .= "<currency>" . $_currency . "</currency>";
    $strxml .= "<pmethod></pmethod>";
    $strxml .= "<expiry_limit></expiry_limit>";
    $strxml .= "<trxtype>Sale</trxtype>";
    $strxml .= "<client_ip>" . $_clientip . "</client_ip>";
    $strxml .= "<mlogo_url></mlogo_url>";// pls set this to the url where your logo is hosted

    // $item['name'] = 'item1';
    // $item['qty'] = 0;
    // $item['amount'] = 100.00;
    $amt = number_format((float)10, 2, '.', '');

    $strxml .= "<orders>";
        $strxml .= "<items>";
            // item 1
            $strxml .= "<Items>";
                $strxml .= "<itemname>item 1</itemname>";
                $strxml .= "<quantity>1</quantity>";
                $strxml .= "<amount>".$amt."</amount>";
            $strxml .= "</Items>";

            // item 2
            $strxml .= "<Items>";
                $strxml .= "<itemname>item 2</itemname>";
                $strxml .= "<quantity>1</quantity>";
                $strxml .= "<amount>".$amt."</amount>";
            $strxml .= "</Items>";
        $strxml .= "</items>";
    $strxml .= "</orders>";

    $strxml .= "<secure3d>" . $_sec3d . "</secure3d>";
    $strxml .= "<signature>" . $_sign . "</signature>";
$strxml .= "</Request>";


$b64string =  base64_encode($strxml);


 ?>
```

here is my submit form

```
<form name="surecollect" id="surecollect" method="post" action="https://testpti.payserv.net/webpaymentv2/default.aspx">
    <input type="hidden" name="paymentrequest" value="<?php echo $b64string; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's been a lot of changes on Paynamics recently. Please follow this repl.it as example and replace `xxxx` with the keys provided to `enter code here`you by Paynamics. [paynamics.php](https://repl.it/@KBPsystem777/paynamics-test)

Make sure line 41 is equals to `$_amount`. Formula is `Amount = <quantity /> * <amount />`

Comment: @JamVille can you please elaborate what you need when u say decode?

Answer (score 0):

Signature is key sensitive. You should lowercase all letters